# "Switch off" motor with dronekit-python ('glider' as a vehicle)

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit, mavlink

I'm working on a project which aims to build an autonomous glider to launch from  a weather balloon, using a Raspberry Pi, Dronekit, and a PixHawk.

To test our navigation algorithms, we're flying the RC plane up to 400ft (legal limit) and then switching to automation software.

Is there any way to get Dronekit to treat our vehicle as a *glider* rather than a *plane*? i.e. so it will only control the ailerons, and not the propeller, once we switch to the automation software. This is only an issue for the test flights, as for the proper thing we simply won't connect the propeller.